# Proper way to map complex JSON as a Java object with Retrofit and GSON

Tags: java, android, generics, gson, retrofit2

If the JSON Object I'm getting from the REST API has the following structure:

```
{

"IsError":false,

"Result":{ "key1":"value", "key2":"value", ... }

}
```

Should two different Java classes (IsError and Result) be composed or only one including both, as the expected Object in the Call<>?

**Update 06th October 2016:**

Proper usage with Retrofit2 asked [in a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39901077/complex-json-with-generics-using-retrofit2)

Comment: Well, just use this site and find out.  http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org

Comment: Thank you @cricket_007 I did and suggested to create two two objects per call, being one for the Response and one for the Result. I would like to only have one Response object and several Result ones. Anny suggestion?

Comment: Got it, posted a new question about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your services are going to respond with that structure, then I would implement a generic class that includes both `IsError` and `Result`:

```
public class Response<T> {
    private boolean IsError;
    private T Result;

    // getters
}
```

Then for each service you would have to use the corresponding classes, e.g. `Response<MyClass1>`, `Response<MyClass2>`, etc. as the expected object in the `Call<>`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Fernandespr, to be clear, then MyClass1, MyClass2, etc would extend Response and override the generic T Result to a specific-structured Object, right?

Comment: Actually, you should use it like this: `Call<Response<MyClass1>>` or `Call<Response<MyClass2>>`.

Comment: Hi @fernandospr I've added more details about this question. What do you think?