# Complex JSON with generics using Retrofit2

Tags: java, generics, gson, retrofit, retrofit2

In my application, most of the JSON that I receive from the server have the following structure:

```
{

"IsError":false,

"Result":{ "key1":"value", "key2":"value", ... }

}
```

I've followed @fernandospr 's suggestion in [my original question about GSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39338552/proper-way-to-map-complex-json-as-a-java-object-with-retrofit-and-gson) and tried using generics to avoid writing two objects (Response and Result) per JSON and having a generic Response Object which would adapt to any kind of Result; as:

```
public class GenericResponse<T> {

  @SerializedName("IsError")
  private boolean isError;

  @SerializedName("Result")
  private T result;

    public boolean isError() {
      return isError;
  }

  public T result() {
      return result;
  }

}
```

Where I would indicate a specific Object when performing a call. The structure of the Profile Object, replacing the generic T is:

```
public class Profile {

  @SerializedName("UserName")
  private String userName;

  @SerializedName("Stuff")
  private boolean stuff;

  @SerializedName("ListOfStuff")
  private List<String> listOfStuff = new ArrayList<String>();

...

}
```

And then I perform the synchronous call like this:

```
Call<GenericResponse<Profile>> call = Api.getProfile(username);

  try {
    GenericResponse<Profile> response = call.execute().body();

  } catch (IOException e) {
    MUtils.logException(e);
}
```

Then the .body() method returns a null. I've debugged the .body() method and it seems to be working internally but the parsing doesn't work. I have reasons to believe parsing is the problem because with this simpler JSON object (doesn't require a separate Result Object) in another call .body() returns the object as it should:

```
public class ConfirmPasswordResponse {

  @SerializedName("isError")
  private boolean isError;

  @SerializedName("Result")
  private boolean Result;

  public boolean isError() {
      return isError;
  }

  public boolean result() {
      return Result;
  }

}
```

Comment: Your result is an object, not a boolean, so yes, the parsing probably failed.

Comment: When the result is a boolean it works because I use the object ConfirmPasswordResponse for the full JSON. When it doesn't work is when I receive an object and I try to process it through generics specifying an object such as Profile

Comment: Okay, I see. Well, what does the `Result` key look like when you do have a `Profile` object?

Comment: The key is always `Result`

Comment: {
"IsError":false,

"Result":{"UserName":"SomeName","Stuff":"SuperStuff","ListOfStuff":["Stuff1","Stuff2"]}

}